# How to detect all tests (in multiple files) finished

Tags: mocha.js

I would like to drop database after all tests in all files ran. Is there a hook for it in Mocha?

`after()` hook can be applied only within 1 file only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a root level hook in mocha. For your case, you can create a new file and specify drop database command in `after` function. That's it!

```
// init-test.js

after(function() {
  // drop database
});
```

You don't need to move any test in other test file for this solution.

Reference:
https://mochajs.org/#root-level-hooks

Answer (score 1):

Create a parent file that includes/requires all other tests, then use `after` within that file:

```
describe('User', () => {
  require('../user/user.spec.js')
})

describe('Post', () => {
  require('../post/post.spec.js')
})

describe('Tag', () => {
  require('../tag/tag.spec.js')
})

describe('Routes', () => {
  require('./routes.spec.js')
})

after(() => {
  // drop database
})
```

Comment: Cleaner than `process.on('exit')` but to me seems a little bit more complex because I'd have to remember to add the test suites. A great idea still! +1

Comment: I'm curious, since you're running multiple test files, in which test file do you put the `process.on('exit')` handler? The last one that runs?

Comment: I've updated my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54289273/1075289) to show how I'm using it in multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `process.on('exit')`. It works when running only one file as well as when running tests from **package.json**.

database.mocha-base.js:

```
db.connect()

process.on('exit', async () => {
  console.log('All tests finished. Droping database')
  db.dropDatabase(dbName)
  db.disconnect()
})

module.exports = {
  applyHooks() {
     before(async () => {
        // truncate tables
     })
  }
}
```

I'm including `database.mocha-base.js`  in all tests that need database access:

```
const dbMochaBase = require('./path/to/database.mocha-base.js')

describe('Tests', () => {
   dbMochaBase.applyHooks()

   ...
})
```

Comment: Doesn't this hang the exit process?

Comment: @NikKyriakides can you please explain me what do you mean by "hanging the exit process"?

Comment: prevent the process from exiting

Comment: I'm usually just an empirical guy and it doesn't hang it for me in this case.

Comment: Got it; I wasn't sure if it does, was just asking.